# How to Change VS-Code Tab setting from "Change Focus" to "Add Spaces"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After latest VS-Code update, tab feature changes to "focus change" instead of adding space or identation.  i try change every setting in `setting.json` but it not wotrking. it is really annoying as i am use to it.
Any Help would be appreciated.

```
{
"workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"prettier.singleQuote": true,
"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"indenticator.hover.peekBack": 0,
"indenticator.hover.peekForward": 1,
"indenticator.inner.hover.peekBack": 0,
"indenticator.inner.hover.peekForward": 1,
"indenticator.inner.showHighlight": true,
"html.format.endWithNewline": true,
"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true,
"prettier.printWidth": 110,
"html.format.indentHandlebars": true,
"html.format.indentInnerHtml": true,
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe",
"prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true,
"prettier.trailingComma": "es5",
"prettier.useTabs": true,
"angular2-switcher.openSideBySide": true,
"editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation",
"editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
},
"[less]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "michelemelluso.code-beautifier"
},
"workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
"workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
"editor.renderControlCharacters": false,
"editor.showFoldingControls": "always",
"editor.smoothScrolling": true,
"breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
"terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
},
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

}

This is my settings file. Extensions settings are same as before.

Comment: So annoying.. I've apparently hit ctrl-m a few times by mistake. To get out of this mode, restarting VS Code also works, but ctrl-m is much easier! (Might need to remove that keybinding..)

Comment: @LightCC yes but ctrl+m was nit working for me either at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While backing up my VS-Code settings on cloud i found (in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Code\User` > `keybindings.json`) that tab was assigned as `-tab` labeled to `move-focus`. which did'nt appear on UI settings on Vs-Code.
i dont know where it came from (after 2nd Last VS-Code Update):

```
 {
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "-tab",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && !editorTabMovesFocus"
}
```

i just removed it . And it Works same as `DEFAULT`.

Sharing this as answer if anyone faces this problem from nowhere. 
Thank You. :)

Answer (score 25):

In the command palette, use *Toggle Tab Key Moves Focus* (Ctrl + M by default as of 1.36.0) to switch between these modes.

Comment: I didn't find that command in the palette, but `Ctrl + M` did the trick for me.