# vscode: How to make tab key indent instead of changing focus?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in an open editor window in Visual Studio Code, the focus changes from the editor pane to other window components.

Instead, I would like it to indent text.

This behavior is not impacted by which Language Mode is active. I would also like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to dedent/un-indent, which currently also changes focus of editor components, but in reverse order.

I'm not sure how vscode changed from my desired behavior from the current behavior; it has always functioned in my desired way until it unexpectedly changed today.

Comment: Check the keybindings for `Tab` - one of them should have the command `tab` and an `editorTextFocus && ...` when clause.  Is that one missing?

Comment: @Mark: Keybinding is: editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && !editorTabMovesFocus

Comment: I must have hit Ctrl+M on accident. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56921891/5389585

Comment: @sondra.kinsey I suggest you answer your own question and accept it. The question title is to the point and many people (who are impatient like me) will decide to scroll down to answers after having read only that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>**. This feature is called "[Tab Trapping](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility#_tab-trapping)". When active, the words "Tab Moves Focus" appear in the [status bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface), and you can also deactive the feature by clicking these words. You probably activated this inadvertently by typing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> sequence, which toggles this setting.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the command `Toggle Tab Key Moves Focus` with this in your keybindings.json:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "command": "-editor.action.toggleTabFocusMode"
  }
```

or right-click on thetat command in the `Keyboard Shortcuts` editor and choose `Remove Keybinding` and then you would be unable to accidentally engage the `Tab Moves Focus` mode in the future.